# How to select rows from different point in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do i select/slice from multiple points which is in this case, starting from `max()` for the for all the columns. each stock has its own max value, so it shall begin selections from that particular point.

```
df
>>>                                     TSLA             MSFT
2017-05-15 00:00:00+00:00                314              68
2017-05-16 00:00:00+00:00                319              69
2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00                320              61
2017-05-18 00:00:00+00:00                313              66
2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00                316              70
2017-05-22 00:00:00+00:00                314              65
2017-05-23 00:00:00+00:00                310              63


max_idx = df.idxmax() # returns index of max value
>>> TSLA    2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00
>>> MSFT    2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00

max_value = df.max() # returns max value
>>> TSLA = 320
>>> MSFT = 70
```

Is their any way like using,
`df2 = df.loc[max_idx:]`
i want the output such that i can later find the max_value and max_idx again on this new output starting from,

```
TSLA    2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00  
MSFT    2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00
```

> **EDIT :** am expecting the following output:

```
   df2
>>> TSLA                                  MSFT
    2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00     320     2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00   70
    2017-05-18 00:00:00+00:00     313     2017-05-22 00:00:00+00:00   65     
    2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00     316     2017-05-23 00:00:00+00:00   63       
    2017-05-22 00:00:00+00:00     314             
    2017-05-23 00:00:00+00:00     310
```

Similar to how @Unutbu used Multindexing, the new dataframe can be multindexed if possible.

Just for example, i only posted 2 columns, but their will be 100's of columns,
so please keep in mind such big data. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU pd.read_clipboard() is your friend here.

Comment: i can accept any form of output, i just want to be able to find the max value starting from `TSLA    2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00  
MSFT    2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00` @MaxU you have freedom to use any form.

Comment: @MaxU no, i found only deep embarrasment.

Comment: @ArJuN, a solution will depend on your desired data set ;-)

Comment: wait i'll post my desired output @MaxU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `apply` method:

```
In [204]: df.apply(lambda s: s.loc[s.idxmax():])
Out[204]: 
            MSFT  TSLA
2017-05-17   NaN   320
2017-05-18   NaN   313
2017-05-19  70.0   316
2017-05-22  65.0   314
2017-05-23  63.0   310
```

or, building on [MaxU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45614716/190597),

```
In [205]: pd.concat({c:df.loc[max_idx[c]:, c] for c in df.columns}).unstack(level=0)
Out[205]: 
            MSFT   TSLA
2017-05-17   NaN  320.0
2017-05-18   NaN  313.0
2017-05-19  70.0  316.0
2017-05-22  65.0  314.0
2017-05-23  63.0  310.0
```

Both of these solutions loop over the columns. (`df.apply`'s loop is done under
the hood, but it amounts to a Python-speed loop performance-wise.) I know you
are looking for a vectorized solution but in this case I don't see a way to
avoid the loop.

---

If you want to avoid the NaNs, you could leave the answer unstacked:

```
In [208]: pd.concat({c:df.loc[max_idx[c]:, c] for c in df.columns})
Out[208]: 
MSFT  2017-05-19     70
      2017-05-22     65
      2017-05-23     63
TSLA  2017-05-17    320
      2017-05-18    313
      2017-05-19    316
      2017-05-22    314
      2017-05-23    310
dtype: int64
```

or, if you're using `df.apply`, call `stack` to move the columns labels into a level of the row index:

```
In [213]: df.apply(lambda s: s.loc[s.idxmax():]).T.stack()
Out[213]: 
MSFT  2017-05-19     70.0
      2017-05-22     65.0
      2017-05-23     63.0
TSLA  2017-05-17    320.0
      2017-05-18    313.0
      2017-05-19    316.0
      2017-05-22    314.0
      2017-05-23    310.0
dtype: float64
```

---

So let's look at performance. With this setup (to test on a bigger DataFrame):

```
shape = (1000,2000)
bigdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=shape),
                     index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N))

def using_apply(df):
    return df.apply(lambda s: s.loc[s.idxmax():])

def using_loop(df):
    max_idx = df.idxmax()
    return pd.concat({c:df.loc[max_idx[c]:, c] for c in df.columns}).unstack(level=0)
```

MaxU's `using_loop` is slightly faster than `using_apply`:

```
In [202]: %timeit using_apply(bigdf)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.45 s per loop

In [203]: %timeit using_loop(bigdf)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop
```

Note, however, that it is best to test benchmarks on your own machine as results
may vary.

Comment: Thats great, thanks..but now how do i find max value and idx staring from `2017-05-19  MSFT     70
2017-05-17  TSLA    320`, which function shall i use, am new to pandas, please help.

Comment: am sorry i didn't questioned specifically to what i want, i edited the question and now i clearly mentioned how the output shall be, can you please edit your answer unutbu?

Comment: Thanks a Lot @unutbu, u made my day. God bless you!

Answer (score 2):

We could do something like this:

```
In [120]: {c:df.loc[max_idx[c]:, c].max() for c in df.columns}
Out[120]: {'MSFT': 70, 'TSLA': 320}
```

Comment: thats awesome man, but one problem here, since i'll be dealing with 100's of columns/stocks for loop may degrade my performance, but i really like your answer, i'll try both solutions provided by you and unutbu and will choose one, i'll defenitely upvote your answer once i become eligible.

Comment: i edited the question and specified how the output shall look like finally, and sorry it was my mistake that i wasnt able to convey how my output shall look like, can you do something now?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to slice based on the index of the max, you can use:

```
df[(df.index > max_idx.TSLA) & (df.index > max_idx.TSLA)]
```

which gives you the rows with a timestamp greater than both maxima (you could choose one or the other, I wasn't sure what you wanted.)

Comment: We could do `df.loc[max_idx.max():]`, but i'm not sure OP wants something like this...

Comment: @MaxU that could yield dataset of just one stock, but i wanted for both the columns.

Comment: @Stael, thanks for the answer. but can it slice for multiple stocks at once?

Comment: @MaxU i hope now u know what i want, so if you have the solution in ur mind, feel free to post the answer, i'll compare which answer is easy and will accept that :)

Comment: @ArJuN, when we slice DF - it must have a square form - same number of rows for all columns...

Comment: @MaxU Yes, it does have same number of rows for all columns.

Comment: @ArJuN, no, in general case it doesn't as `df.idxmax()` will return different index values for different columns